# A program that can display charts with data entered from textbox

Tags: vb.net, charts

i want to create a program,whereby my users can enter data through text boxes and it shows on the chart. And they can store it so that the next time the program
 is opened it displays their data. How do i go about the saving the data and entering data through  text boxes.

Comment: Some tutorials on programming in .NET would be a great place to start.  Reading input values and interacting with a database are very fundamental concepts and would be covered by pretty much any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set all de userinput in a string. For storing that string you can maybe put it in a text-file.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt",
```

"This text will be added to the text file",True)

You can output the userinput back again by reading from the text-file.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
```

And set it in a label.